# Como hago para que en un menú en vez de números me acepte letras?

Tags: c

Estoy haciendo un programa tipo calculador, en el se accede al menú suma con 1, resta con 2, multiplicación con 3 y división con 4.luego me pregunte como se haría para que en vez de números fueran letras, como por ejemplo: suma que en vez de ser 1 fuera "s" o que para multiplicación fuera "m".

Intente declarar las variables que usaría para las opciones, todo bien hasta ahí no me marca error incluso puedo elegir la letra pero no me pide los números para realizar la operación  Me podrían ayudar con esto por favor?
Aqui les dejo el código

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    int a, b;
    char salir_continuar, caracter;

    do
    {
          printf("\n s) Suma");
          printf("\n r) Resta");
          printf("\n m) Multiplicacion");
          printf("\n d) Division");
          printf("\n\nElija una opcion: ");
          scanf("%d", &caracter);

  switch(caracter){

     case ('s'): printf("\nIngrese el valor de A: ");
             scanf("%d", &a);
             printf("\nIngrese el valor de B: ");
             scanf("%d", &b);

             printf("\nEl resultado Final: %d",a+b);
             break;


     case ('r'): printf ("\nIngrese el valor de A: ");
                  scanf("%d", &a);
                 printf("\nIngrese el valor de B: ");
                  scanf("%d", &b);

                  printf("\nEl resultado Final: %d", a-b);
                  break;



    case ('m'):   printf("\nIngrese el valor de A: ");
            scanf("%d", &a);
            printf("\nIngrese el valor de B: ");
            scanf("%d", &b);

            printf("\nEl resultado de Final es: %d",a*b);
            break;



    case ('4'): printf("\nIngrese el valor de A: ");
            scanf("%d", &a);
            printf("\nIngrese el valor de B: ");
            scanf("%d", &b);

            printf("\nEl resultado de Final es: %d",  a/b);
            break;


    default: ;

}

     printf("\n\n quiere hacer otra operacion matematica? ...", 168);
     printf("\n\n elija n para salir o s para continuar: ");
     fflush(stdin);
     scanf("%c", &salir_continuar);

    system("cls");

    }while(salir_continuar!='n');

   printf("\n Hasta luego");

   return 0;

}
```

Comment: puedes usar tipos enumerados: enum opciones {SUMA, RESTA, MULTI, DIVIDE, SALIR}; Con esto suma seria 0, resta 1, multi 2 y asi... Luego usas SUMA en el case y correspondera a 0 y asi...

Comment: `%d` indica que quieres leer un numero entero. Para caracteres usas `%c`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esta linea está esperando un número

```
scanf("%d", &caracter);
```

por lo cual en la variable carácter se guarda el numero correspondiente del carácter ASCII. Cambialo por

```
scanf("%c", &caracter);
```

Me salió error en esta linea

```
printf("\n\n quiere hacer otra operacion matematica? ...", 168);
```

asi que lo cambié por

```
printf("\n\n quiere hacer otra operacion matematica? ...");
```

Comment: Vaya... que tonto de mi parte no fijarme en eso jajajaja, Muchas Gracias